# Post request using node-fetch not returning response

Tags: javascript, post, firebase-authentication

I'm new to using node-fetch and catch figure out why I am not getting any response data to print to the console.

Im using a function to generate firebase user auth tokens for testing but I'm not getting any response whereas in postman my requests with the same data are returning what I want. As you can see I've even hard coded the data into the body and still its not returning anything.

```
async function firebaseSetupAuth(){
  const token1 = admin.auth().createCustomToken("xKdXw06u2tUVE72ETrJVwevCNQo1")
  const token2 = await token1
  token = token2
  const url = "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key=AIzaSyBoKaBKWe9x2LS_n5AHCIEM-5AB_dC99mg"
  const fetchBody = {"token": token,"returnSecureToken":true }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(fetchBody))
  const response1 = fetch(url,{
    method: "post",
    body: fetchBody,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  })
  const response2 = await response1
  console.log(response2)
}
```

Comment: If you're going to define your function as `async`, you shouldn't be using `then` in your code.  Use `await` to pause execution after each function that returns a promise.

Comment: I've edited my code to use await

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the result of `fetch`

```js
.then((customToken) => {
    return fetch(url,{ // return on this line
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify(/*stuff*/),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }
  )
  })
```

Comment: I have added the return but still no response printed tot he console

Comment: You can try isolate this further. Try the `fetch` call without `createCustomToken` and see if that returns correctly. If it is, there might be issues in `createCustomToken` or `admin.auth()`.

Comment: everything else functions correctly except for my fetch